# Error trying to join Linux server with AD

Tags: active-directory, samba

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to join a server with my AD machine, but I'm getting this error:

Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain 'MYDOMAIN.LOCAL' over rpc: An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.

Can someone please help me? Clearly something is wrong with something I've done here, but I haven't been able to find the issue with either krb5.conf or smb.conf, or sssd.conf but clearly there must be. I tried to include as much relevant info as I could but I'm sure I probably missed something else to include. I've been trying to fix this for over a day now but everything that I've googled so far has not helped.

```
samba.x86_64                           4.8.3-4.el7                 @base
samba-client.x86_64                    4.8.3-4.el7                 @base
samba-client-libs.x86_64               4.8.3-4.el7                 @anaconda/7.6
samba-common.noarch                    4.8.3-4.el7                 @anaconda/7.6
samba-common-libs.x86_64               4.8.3-4.el7                 @anaconda/7.6
samba-common-tools.x86_64              4.8.3-4.el7                 @base
samba-libs.x86_64                      4.8.3-4.el7                 @base
```

My /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]

config_file_version = 2
debug_level = 7
domains =  mydomain.local
services = nss, pam, sudo
# Uncomment/adjust as needed if IMU is not used:
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash

[domain/mydomain.local]

id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
cache_credentials = true
ad_server = mydomain-11.mydomain.local
ad_backup_server = mydomain-12.mydomain.local
ldap_search_timeout = 20
ldap_opt_timeout = 15
subdomain_inherit = ignore_group_members, ldap_purge_cache_timeout
ldap_purge_cache_timeout = 0

# Enables use of POSIX UIDs and GIDs:
ldap_id_mapping = true
ldap_schema = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
ldap_use_tokengroups = false

[nss]

memcache_timeout = 3600
override_shell = /bin/bash


[pam]

debug_level = 2
pam_id_timeout = 15

#[sudo]
#
#[autofs]
#
[ssh]
#
#[pac]
#
#[ifp]
```

My /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]

            workgroup = MYDOMAIN
            realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
            client signing = yes
            client use spnego = yes
            kerberos method = secrets and keytab
            security = ads
            server string = Samba Server Version %v
            log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
            max log size = 50
            passdb backend = tdbsam
            idmap config * : backend = autorid
            idmap config * : range = 1000000 - 19999999
            idmap config * : rangesize = 1000000
[homes]

    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    writable = yes
[printers]

    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    browseable = no
    guest ok = no
    writable = no
    printable = yes
```

My /etc/krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]

renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
default_realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
ticket_lifetime = 24h
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
#default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
#default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

[domain_realm]
mydomain.local = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

[realms]

MYDOMAIN.LOCAL = (open bracket)
admin_server = mydomain-11.mydomain.local
kdc = MYDOMAIN-11.MYDOMAIN.local
(close bracket)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow! I'm sorry but I think your question is off topic here because it is not related to a programming problem in any way.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.